# Integrating Keras model into TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am trying to use a pre-trained Keras model within TensorFlow code, as described in [this Keras blog post](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) under section II: Using Keras models with TensorFlow.

I want to use the pre-trained VGG16 network available in Keras to extract convolutional feature maps from images, and add my own TensorFlow code over that. So I've done this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K

# images = a NumPy array containing 8 images

model = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=images.shape, dtype=tf.float32)
inputs = preprocess_input(inputs)
features = model(inputs)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    K.set_session(sess)
    output = sess.run(features, feed_dict={inputs: images})
    print(output.shape)
```

However, this gives me an error:

```
FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value block1_conv1_2/kernel
     [[Node: block1_conv1_2/kernel/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](block1_conv1_2/kernel)]]
     [[Node: vgg16_1/block5_pool/MaxPool/_3 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_132_vgg16_1/block5_pool/MaxPool", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

Instead, if I run an initializer op before running the network:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    K.set_session(sess)
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    output = sess.run(features, feed_dict={inputs: images})
    print(output.shape)
```

Then I get the expected output:

```
(8, 11, 38, 512)
```

My question is, upon running `tf.global_variables_initializer()`, have the variables been initialized randomly or with the ImageNet weights? I ask this because the blog post referenced above does not mention that an initializer needs to be run when using pre-trained Keras models, and indeed it makes me feel a bit uneasy.

I suspect that it does use the ImageNet weights, and that one needs to run the initializer only because TensorFlow requires all variables to be explicitly initialized. But this is just a guess.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## TLDR

When using Keras,

1. Avoid using `Session` if you can (in the spirit of agnostic Keras)
2. Use Keras-handled `Session` through `tf.keras.backend.get_session` otherwise.
3. Use Keras' `set_session` for advanced uses (e.g. when you need profiling or device placement) and very early in your program — contrary to common practice and good usage in "pure" Tensorflow.

## More about that

Variables must be initialized before they can be used. Actually, it's a bit more subtle than that: Variables must be initialized **in the session** they are used. Let's look at this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.Variable(0.)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    # x is initialized -- no issue here
    x.eval()
    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    x.eval()
    # Error -- x was never initialized in this session, even though
    # it has been initialized before in another session
```

So it shouldn't come as a surprise that variables from your `model` are not initialized, because you create your model before `sess`.

However, `VGG16` not only creates initializer operations for the model variables (the ones you are calling with `tf.global_variables_initializer`), but actually *does* call them. Question is, within which `Session`?

Well, since none existed at the time you built your model, Keras created a default one for you, that you can recover using `tf.keras.backend.get_session()`. Using this session now works as expected because variables are initialized in this session:

```
with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    K.set_session(sess)
    output = sess.run(features, feed_dict={inputs: images})
    print(output.shape)
```

Note that you could also create your own `Session` and provide it to Keras, through `keras.backend.set_session` — and this is exactly what you have done. But, as this example shows, Keras and TensorFlow have different mindsets.

A TensorFlow user would typically first construct a graph, then instantiate a Session, perhaps after freezing the graph.

Keras is framework-agnostic and does not have this built-in distinction between construction phases — in particular, we learned here that Keras may very well instantiate a Session *during* graph construction.

For this reason, when using Keras, I would advise against managing a `tf.Session` yourself and instead rely on `tf.keras.backend.get_session` if you need to handle TensorFlow specific code that requires a `tf.Session`.

Comment: Good, detailed answer. The usage of `tf.keras.backend.get_session` should have been mentioned in the [official blog post](https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html) where they talk about using a pretrained VGG16 model.

Comment: I have a question (perhaps unrelated, if you suggest I'll post it as a new question): if I define the further layers after `VGG16` in TensorFlow, including a loss and training op, then upon running the training op, will the whole model (including `VGG16`) be trained end-to-end?

Comment: @RohanSaxena Thanks for the edits :-) Yes, VGG16 variables are defined as trainable, so you should be able to retrain the model

Comment: This particular answer did not work for me when I tried it in my project. If I read it right, we get here the session created within Keras with tf.keras.backend.get_session and then set the same session again back to Keras with K.set_session(sess). (I am maybe reading this wrong..) But I replaced "with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:" with "with keras.backend.get_session() as sess:" and removed the line "K.set_session(sess)" and it worked. What is the difference here?

Answer (score 4):

As a complement to @P-Gn's answer, if you insist on explicitly creating a new session (like the tutorial you are reading) you should put these lines:

```
sess = tf.Session()
K.set_session(sess)
```

before creating the model (i.e. `model = VGG16(...)`) and then use the created session like:

```
with sess.as_defualt():
    output = sess.run(features, feed_dict={inputs: images})
```

Comment: Good note. One question on that: if I set the session in Keras (with `K.set_session(sess)`) *before* creating the `VGG16` model, then will Keras use `sess` for initializing the model variables – and not generate a default `Session` via `tf.keras.backend.get_session` as @P-Gn said?

Comment: @RohanSaxena Yes, Keras will use `sess` as its active session and the model variables will be initialized using `sess` session. If you want to make sure, use `print(sess)` and `print(K.get_session())` after setting Keras session (i.e. `K.set_session(sess)`) and use `print(K.get_session())` before setting Keras session. You will see that the first two (i.e. `sess` and `K.get_session()` after setting Keras session) point to the same object.