# Tensorflow Keras RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified. [Minimal working example provided]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm somewhat confused about what I'm seeing with my pretrained keras models. I'm using a virtualenv with tensorflow-gpu=1.13.1 installed via `pip install tensorflow-gpu`. Here's a minimal working example you can run, [based on the keras documentation](https://keras.io/applications/) (hopefully these are updated). In addition, I [got the elephant image from here](https://mondrian.mashable.com/uploads%252Fcard%252Fimage%252F887009%252F49d251da-d190-49d8-80ad-5f12221574b4.jpg%252F950x534__filters%253Aquality%252880%2529.jpg?signature=kgnqs9P47PJJetZVmw6IxI96WmE=&source=https%3A%2F%2Fblueprint-api-production.s3.amazonaws.com) and saved it as `elephant.jpeg`.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

# Load the image.
img_path = 'data/elephant.jpeg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)  # shape (1,224,224,3)
x = preprocess_input(x)

# The basic full model
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')

# Make a session here
sess = tf.Session()
sess.graph.finalize()

# Predict, and decode the results into a list of tuples (class, description,
# probability) (one such list for each sample in the batch)
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=4)[0])
```

Running the code will result in:

```
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Yet the weird thing is that if I change the code to insert a *second* `model.predict` before I finalize the graph, as in here:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np

# Load the image.
img_path = 'data/elephant.jpeg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(224, 224))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)  # shape (1,224,224,3)
x = preprocess_input(x)

# The basic full model
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=4)[0])

# Make a session here
sess = tf.Session()
sess.graph.finalize()

# Predict, and decode the results into a list of tuples (class, description,
# probability) (one such list for each sample in the batch)
preds = model.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=4)[0])
```

In the above there are only two extra lines, I copied the prediction code above with the print statement. This output seems to work and results in both predictions working:

```
Predicted: [('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.5286887), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.4639527), ('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.0072972253), ('n02408429', 'water_buffalo', 2.6213302e-05)]
Predicted: [('n01871265', 'tusker', 0.5286887), ('n02504013', 'Indian_elephant', 0.4639527), ('n02504458', 'African_elephant', 0.0072972253), ('n02408429', 'water_buffalo', 2.6213302e-05)]
```

Here's why I'm confused and asking this question. I don't get why putting the predict code is necessary before a `sess.graph.finalize()` call. I am hoping to use pretrained models solely for feature extraction. That is, I'll pass in a numpy array into the net, and get a numpy array back. (For this I'd have to use the extra `include_top=True` but I didn't do that above for the sake of simplicity.) Then I want to pass this result to a new network that I design, using low-level tensorflow libraries.

It appears that before my `sess.graph.finalize()` call, I need to insert a "dummy" prediction call beforehand to "get the graph set up." Is that intuition right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `predict = model.predict(image)` is being treated as a node in the graph, and once you finalize the graph, you can't modify it further. However, you don't really need a `tf.Session()` in this case, your example can run solely like this:

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 224,224,3)
# The basic full model
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
preds = model.predict(x)

# Predict, and decode the results into a list of tuples (class, description,
# probability) (one such list for each sample in the batch)

print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=4)[0])
```

If you want to read more about it, I assume that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51107527/integrating-keras-model-into-tensorflow) should be really helpful for you. Finally, if you really insist on having a `tf.Session()`, and finalize the graph with it, this should do it for you:

```
x = np.random.rand(1, 224,224,3)
# The basic full model
model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet')
preds = model.predict(x)

with tf.keras.backend.get_session() as sess:
    K.set_session(sess)
    sess.graph.finalize()
    print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds, top=4)[0])
```

Comment: Thanks @gorjan I'll check that question/answer, surprised I didn't see it earlier. Yes, I don't need the session here. I had it in the above example because I am working with a more complicated code base that uses it, and I tried to simplify it down for the minimal working example.

Comment: Good! I included an additional code snippet for further explanation. Feel free to check it out!